# CURL error (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated)

Tags: curl, php

> Warning: curl_setopt()
>   [function.curl-setopt]:
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be
>   activated when in safe_mode or an
>   open_basedir is set in
>   /home/path/curl.php on line 594

I don't have access to php.ini. Can this be fixed without editing php.ini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#71313) in the manual. It provides an ugly workaround. I believe this restriction is effect because of a bug in the curl library where it would follow redirects to local resources, but that should be fixed by now, so I see no reason for this restriction.

Comment: Well that's an ugly hack for sure, but it works - basically, you will parse the response headers and redirect manually.

Answer (score 0):

`safe_mode` belongs to `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` - so if that's the issue, you're out of luck, these items can only be set in php.ini and vhost config.

`open_basedir` belongs to `PHP_INI_ALL`, so you could set it in `.htaccess` using `php_value`.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think php_admin_value cannot be put in .htaccess files. Perhaps you mean php_value?

Comment: @Artefacto: You are correct, fixed. "php_admin_value (...) This can not be used in .htaccess files." http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Answer (score 0):

This is Worked for me!

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        $header=array(
          'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0',
          'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
          'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
          'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
          'Keep-Alive: 115',
          'Connection: keep-alive',
        );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'curl_cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'curl_cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);

     $status = curl_getinfo($curl);

 if ($status['http_code'] == 200) {
    return $data;    
} else {
    echo $url;
    return @file_get_contents($url);
}
```